# Select from a table based on a regex split from another table using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, join

I have a query that runs on a CLOB, splits the column up, and filters based on a string. Here's the query:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT
        TRIM(typesettings) AS str
    FROM
        layout
) SELECT
    regexp_substr(str,'(\d+\DINSTANCE\D\w*)',1,level)
  FROM
    t
WHERE
    regexp_substr(str,'(\d+\DINSTANCE\D\w*)',1,level) LIKE '56_INSTANCE_%'
CONNECT BY
    level <= regexp_count(str,'(\d+\DINSTANCE\D\w*)');
```

Here's a sample of the output from the above query:

```sql
56_INSTANCE_324rtde32r
56_INSTANCE_4mkl4323o4
56_INSTANCE_rr312ek121
```

I want to use the results from the above query to select the ID from another table (called journal). I cannot figure out the correct way to use the result set to do another select. The "with" notation is throwing me off.

Anyone have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: Is this value `56_INSTANCE_324rtde32r`  is the ID you want to use to search in another table?

Comment: You can use one more CTE on the top of your current CTE.

Comment: Yes, each of those values (plus thousands more) are IDs in another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cascade further subqueries in WITH clause in this way:

```
WITH alias1 AS (
   some-query
),
alias2 AS (
  SELECT ... FROM alias1 ......
),
alias3 AS (
  SELECT ... FROM alias2 ......
),
.....
.....
.....
alias99 AS (
  SELECT ... FROM alias33 ....
)
/* the last query */
SELECT ... 
FROM alias99 JOIN alias55 ON ....
WHERE id IN ( select id FROM alias47 )
....
```

---

you can also use the whole WITH query as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   WITH x as (
      SELECT * FROM dual 
  )
  SELECT * FROM x
);
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM dual
WHERE dummy IN (
   WITH x as (
      SELECT * FROM dual 
  )
  SELECT * FROM x
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use like the below

```
select regexp_substr(str,'(\d+\DINSTANCE\D\w*)',1,level) from
(SELECT
    TRIM(typesettings) AS str
FROM
    layout) t
WHERE
regexp_substr(str,'(\d+\DINSTANCE\D\w*)',1,level) LIKE '56_INSTANCE_%'
CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(str,'(\d+\DINSTANCE\D\w*)');
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning that up!